# Why does my checkbox return the wrong state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm really confused. I have the following html in a form:

```
<input class="check-box" 
  id="Data__Correct" 
  name="Data.Correct" 
  type="checkbox" value="Data.Correct" />
```

This creates the following on the web page

```
 <input class="check-box" 
      id="Data__Correct" 
      name="Data.Correct" 
      type="checkbox" value="False" />
```

When I put a check in the checkbox, submit the form, and check with [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) I see it's sending:

```
Data.Correct    False
```

I thought it should be the other way around. What's happening?

Comment: @Barcino Wouldn't the checkbox need to have the `checked` attribute to be seen in Fiddler and sent back to the server?

Comment: what u r asking for?? please shape ur question properly

Comment: Above is the html for my page. When my page displays in the browser I check the checkbox and then click submit. When I check fiddler I see the value being sent back to the server is Data.Correct=False

Comment: @diEcho: please shape YOUR comment properly. 'ur' and 'r' don't exactly inspire confidence in YOUR abilities.

Comment: @Barcino: if your server is receiving the literal text 'false' as the value for that checkbox, then something in your javascript is overwiting the 'Data.Correct' value with the text 'false'.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any javascript doing anything that I know of.

Comment: Could you check that the server itself is receiving the appropriate form data? I don't have any experience with fiddler and I imagaine most people here don't either.

Comment: I did and it's not getting the correct data. It's gets False

Comment: So the server changes value="Data.Correct" with the string False. So there mus be some templating going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how checkbox works.  If the checkbox is unchecked then no value is passed to the backend.  If the checkbox IS checked then the value in the `value` attribute is passed to the backend.  In your case, you set value to `False`, so you are getting the **string** `False` not to be confused with the boolean value false.

If your intent with `value='False'` is to set the state of the checkbox on load, then you instead need to do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ... checked/>
```

Or `checked="checked"` should also work I believe.  If checked is present then the box is checked, otherwise it is unchecked.